# Make div inside overlay scroll

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="first-use-overlay overlay-bg hide">
    <div class="first-user-overlay-shell">
       .....
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following css

```
.first-user-overlay-shell {
    width: 90%;
    min-width: 1200px;
    max-width: 1380px;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.overlay-bg {
    z-index: 105;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
}
```

Basically, when I click a button it opens up an overlay with a div (first-user-overlay-shell) that is another page of the side.

I added a no scroll to the body of the page.

I'm trying to make it so that content inside first-user-overlay-shell scrolls though the body has a no-scoll css. How can I do that?

Comment: Instead of preventing scroll, you could try adding `overflow: hidden` to the body, which prevents the page from visually scrolling, while allowing the page to scroll if your modal high enough. Example is bootstrap's modal: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one, add 1 div after  `first-user-overlay-shell` then add height or just check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1rfyqjd/1/).